# Get rid of the derivatives and relativistic mass in Feynman lectures

Tags: special-relativity, differentiation, mass-energy, integration, calculus

i have a problem with get rid of the derivatives in Feynman lectures (chapter 15, Equivalence of mass and energy). The problem: 
we have $\frac {d(mc^2)}{dt} = v\cdot \frac {d(mv)}{dt}$, then we multiplying both sides by $\\2m$, which changes the equation to $\\c2(2m)\frac {dm}{dt}=2mv\frac {d(mv)}{dt}$. Now Feynman says that we need get rid of derivative in this equation and for doing this we need integrating both sides. *** The quantity $\\(2m)dm/dt$ can be recognized as the time derivative of $\\m^2$, and $\\(2mv)⋅d(mv)/dt$ is the time derivative of $\\(mv)^2$. *** Can anyone explain this last sentence?
P.S: I think, here we try to find antiderivative of both sides,but is the derivative of $\\m^2$ (antiderivative) not equal to $\\2m$ and so on

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)^2=2f(x)\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @probably_someone that is, here the mass is no longer a constant but a function?

Comment: That is how it is being treated, yes. Feynman is just trying to be completely agnostic about the properties of $m$ and $v$ here; if one or the other are constant, this reasoning is still trivially true.